# How can I fix "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '_cmp.pyi'" in my Python nix flake?

Tags: python, nix, nixos, nixpkgs

I'm trying to install jupyter-book on NixOS. I have this flake:

```hs
{
  description = "Introduction to Computational Literary Analysis, a Textbook";

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs }: let
    system = "x86_64-linux";
    pkgs = import nixpkgs { inherit system; };
  in {
    jupyterBook = pkgs.callPackage ./jupyter-book.nix {};

    myPython = (nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system}.python3.withPackages
      (ps: with ps; [
        # pip
        jupyter
        jupyterlab
        self.jupyterBook
        pandas
        nltk
        # spacy
      ]));

    defaultPackage.${system} = self.myPython;
  };
}
```

Which imports jupyter-book.nix, containing this expression:

```hs
{ python3Packages }:

let
  inherit (python3Packages) buildPythonPackage fetchPypi;
  attrs = buildPythonPackage rec {
    pname = "attrs";
    version = "20.3.0";
    src = fetchPypi {
      inherit pname; inherit version;
      sha256 = "007pchhxk2nh6m2rgflkkij9xjwysq3fl7xr72cy8i4pw76s6al3";
    };
    propagatedBuildInputs = with python3Packages; [
      pytest
    ];
  };
  click = buildPythonPackage rec {
    pname = "click";
    version = "7.1";
    src = fetchPypi {
      inherit pname; inherit version;
      sha256 = "1qk0x1bh6pmn2al9kq6cbgvm7pchnzl6ahf4zzpbjljl5lpmabs8";

    };
  };
  jupytext = buildPythonPackage rec {
    pname = "jupytext";
    version = "1.10.3";
    src = fetchPypi {
      inherit pname; inherit version;
      sha256 = "09f0ra3ndq4sxb0q3pjx713pfyc731y6fkzx93481mc7qm2cym5x";
    };
    propagatedBuildInputs = with python3Packages; [
      toml
      pyyaml
      markdown-it-py
    ];
  };
  markdown-it-py = buildPythonPackage rec {
    pname = "markdown-it-py";
    version = "0.6.0";
    src = fetchPypi {
      inherit pname; inherit version;
      sha256 = "0nb6i1hqlipbcpdd7kad26sfhwjxaqnd6md7piaslyzg77gi650w";
    };
    propagatedBuildInputs = with python3Packages; [
      attrs
    ];
  };
  sphinxExternalTOC = buildPythonPackage rec {
    # https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-comments/
    pname = "sphinx-external-toc";
    version = "0.2.2";
    src = fetchPypi {
      pname = "sphinx_external_toc";
      inherit version;
      sha256 = "a72c5861f670f1c7a1b92f2159fc9c7c5370e079cad1e3a7be4b269fa8048e8a";
    };
    propagatedBuildInputs = with python3Packages; [
      sphinx
      attrs
      click
      pyyaml
    ];
  };
  sphinxComments = buildPythonPackage rec {
    # https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-comments/
    pname = "sphinx-comments";
    version = "0.0.3";
    src = fetchPypi {
      inherit version; inherit pname;
      sha256 = "00170afff27019fad08e421da1ae49c681831fb2759786f07c826e89ac94cf21";
    };
    propagatedBuildInputs = with python3Packages; [
      sphinx
    ];
  };
in buildPythonPackage rec {
  pname = "jupyter-book";
  version = "0.11.2";
  src = fetchPypi {
    inherit version; inherit pname;
    sha256 = "e32298e03c19f514c745062891143693c5e001a098bae9d59d2e4434b2099c54";
  };
  propagatedBuildInputs = with python3Packages; [
    # click
    linkify-it-py
    sphinx
    sphinxComments
    sphinxExternalTOC
    jupytext
  ];
}
```

However, when I try to build it using `nix build`, or get a shell with it with `nix shell`, or use `nix develop`, I get this error:

```
❯ nix build
warning: Git tree '/home/jon/Code/book-computational-literary-analysis' is dirty
error: builder for '/nix/store/pp9074i7bmmvfmff4lkdmnj2wkj8vdaj-python3.8-attrs-20.3.0.drv' failed with exit code 1;
       last 10 log lines:
       > Executing pipInstallPhase
       > /build/attrs-20.3.0/dist /build/attrs-20.3.0
       > Processing ./attrs-20.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
       > Installing collected packages: attrs
       >   Attempting uninstall: attrs
       >     Found existing installation: attrs 21.2.0
       >     Uninstalling attrs-21.2.0:
       > ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '_cmp.pyi'
       > Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
       > 
       For full logs, run 'nix log /nix/store/pp9074i7bmmvfmff4lkdmnj2wkj8vdaj-python3.8-attrs-20.3.0.drv'.
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/liza7vix65mk26yc8lfxcsb1xl65ljrs-python3-3.8.9-env.drv' failed to build
```

What's happening here, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `attrs` derivation wants to uninstall the `attrs` library it found via `pytest` dependencies.
Maybe you can build it by removing `pytest` from your `attrs` inputs and disabling checks.

```hs
  attrs = buildPythonPackage rec {
    pname = "attrs";
    version = "20.3.0";
    src = fetchPypi {
      inherit pname; inherit version;
      sha256 = "007pchhxk2nh6m2rgflkkij9xjwysq3fl7xr72cy8i4pw76s6al3";
    };
    doCheck = false;
  };
```

The `attrs` package in Nixpkgs goes a step further by adding a `tests.pytest` attribute allowing to run the tests separately. Such complexity doesn't seem worthwhile here.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Maybe you could also help with the next error I ran into: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68793147/how-can-i-fix-errno-13-permission-denied-nix-store-in-my-python-nix